# how to write this eval in python?

Tags: python, eval

I want to value the following `dict` `y1~y10[name]` with the given list.

I know using `eval(self.y$i[name]) = value` is wrong but how should I do this in python?

```
class excel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_year = 2004
        self.y1 = {'year':self.base_year}
        self.y2 = {'year':self.base_year + 1}
        self.y3 = {'year':self.base_year + 2}
        self.y4 = {'year':self.base_year + 3}
        self.y5 = {'year':self.base_year + 4}
        self.y6 = {'year':self.base_year + 5}
        self.y7 = {'year':self.base_year + 6}
        self.y8 = {'year':self.base_year + 7}
        self.y9 = {'year':self.base_year + 8}
        self.y10 = {'year':self.base_year + 9}
    def value(self, name, value_list):
        for value, i in value_list, range(1, 10):
            eval(self.y$i[name]) = value

list = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 ]
e1.value('test', list)
```

Comment: Why don't you just make a list or dict called `self.y`?  Then you wouldn't need `eval()` or similar things in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The temptation to use introspection &c for mundane tasks is a strong code smell which suggests rethinking your approach -- here, as others have mentioned, making `self.y` a list of `dicts` is a much better idea.  You also need other fixes in your code, though.

```
class excel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_year = 2004
        self.y = [{'year':self.base_year+i} for i in range(10)]
    def value(self, name, value_list):
        for i, value in enumerate(value_list):
            self.y[i][name] = value
```

Yes, this `self.y` is base-0 (goes 0 to 9) -- that's inevitably a lot simpler in programming, and simplicity is such a precious virtue I wouldn't want to give it up...

Answer (score 4):

No need to use `eval` when `getattr` will do:

```
getattr(self, 'y%u' % i)[name] = value
```

But it would be better to put your y#s in a list. So that you can do:

```
self.y[i][name] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using eval for this any more than Kevin or Dan D. do, but to answer your questions, you can use:

```
yi = eval( "self.y{0}".format(i) )
yi[name] = value;
```

The eval() function evaluates an expression, but an assignment with =, +=, etc. is not an expression in Python.  It's a statement.  Thus, I used eval() go get the dict reference into a local variable (y) and used that reference to set the member of the dict that it references.

You can also glue those two statements together and eliminate the yi local variable:

```
eval("self.y{0}".format(i))[name] = value;
```

However, like the others have said, this is not the best way to do this.  A dict, list or even a tuple of dictionaries do the job better.  (See Alex Martelli's example.)

Comment: Thank you and @Dan D. for point out my old way is bad and still gave out the answer. You guys are greats. Thanks again.